# How to get array overlaps using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, arrays

Suppose I have the following arrays:

```
List<int[]> numbers = new List<int[]>();
numbers.Add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
numbers.Add(new int[] { 3, 4, 5 });
numbers.Add(new int[] { 5, 6, 7 });

int[] numbersToFind = new int[] { 4, 5, 6 };
```

I want to find which of the `numbers` elements contains one/more of the values in `numbersToFind`, is there an easy way of doing this with LINQ? That is, some code that would return a `IEnumerable<int[]>` containing an `int[]{3,4,5}` and `int[]{5,6,7}` in the above example.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
numbers.Where(array => array.Any(value => numbersToFind.Contains(value)));
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var query = numbers.Where(n => numbersToFind.Any(x => n.Contains(x)));
```

Here's an alternative approach using the method `Enumerable.Intersect`:

```
var query = numbers.Where(n => numbersToFind.Intersect(n).Any());
```

Answer (score 4):

```
IEnumerable<int[]> matches = numbers.Where(n => numbersToFind.Intersect(n).Any());
```

Comment: +1 I just added this to my answer, but you beat me by a couple of minutes. I think this is probably better than the top voted answer. :)

Comment: Intersect() is going to create a `HashMap<int>` for each evaluation of the Where lambda.  Therefore it will be slower, consume more memory, and create more GC churn.  (At least in this limited example.)

Comment: @cdhowie: I think it will scale better though - I haven't tested it to be sure. I'm not sure if the example in the OPs question should be understood as a representative example of the sort of query he will be doing or if it has been simplified for the purposes of explanation. I'd guess the latter.

Comment: It will not scale.  For *each* number in *each* source array being considered, a brand new `HashMap<int>` will be created and populated with the contents of `numbersToFind`.  My example will iterate over every element of `numbersToFind` until a match is found, where `Intersect()` is going to construct a `HashMap<int>` and **iterate over EVERY element** to build up the hash map, and *finally* check if it contains the value being considered.  I'm sorry, but it's impossible for that to be faster under **any** circumstances.

Comment: If speed is a huge concern, then `numbersToFind` should itself be a `HashMap<int>`.  Then my example would perform even faster.

Comment: @cdhowie - This approach does indeed scale since `Intersect` is linear in the length of the longest collection (at the cost of increased temporary space requirements), whereas the search in your method is O(mn) where m and n are the lengths of the two collections. GC collections are very cheap for short-lived objects so shouldn't be an issue if there are a large number of elements.

Comment: Ah, I completely misread the query, my apologies.  However, this example would still take more time if the numbers to find is a small list and there are a lot of arrays of numbers to search, since a small hashmap will be created over and over.  So performance will depend heavily on what the OP is actually doing.  I still maintain that if speed is really important, `numbersToFind` should be a `HashSet<int>` anyway -- create it once and use it a lot of times instead of repeatedly creating it.

Comment: @cdhowie - I agree that your approach is probably better since it's easier to understand and is probably quicker unless there are a large number of elements in the searched arrays.

Comment: Nod.  I think the consensus here is that all approaches will perform very differently depending on the input.

Comment: I was the OP, and thanks a lot for all your comments/answers. Performance is a big concern actually, so this is all interesting to me. This was a  simplified example of what I'm trying to do, and @cdhowie's way is working well so far. I can't seem to get the Intersect() way working on my real code to compare them though - I keep getting "type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage" errors so I'm obviously doing something wrong there.

Comment: @miket2e - I suggest specifying the type parameters explicitly e.g. `numbers.Where<int[]>(...)` which will either compile or give you a more specific error.

Answer (score 4):

There is a LINQ function `Intersect` specifically to do this:

`numbers.Intersect(numbersToFind)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
numbers.Where(a => a.Any(s => numbersToFind.Contains(s)));
```

Good luck!